# Inserting jquery slider in gridview rows

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, slider

-- I am using asp.net to create a gridview control and I want to add a jquery slider in one the column that is set to a predefined value. My approach was to use the gridview's row created event to call the slider function with the predefined value, but when the page renders there are no sliders. Any ideas on why?

```
  <%@ Page Title="" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" CodeBehind="AssessmentLoggedIn.aspx.vb" Inherits="BCEE_KAIV2.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
    <!-- HTTP 1.1 -->
<meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-store"/>
<!-- HTTP 1.0 -->
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache"/>
<!-- Prevents caching at the Proxy Server -->
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0"/>
    <style type="text/css">
        .btnHolder {
            text-align: center;
            width: 175px;
            margin: 0 auto;

        }
    #slider {
        float: left;
        width: 305px;
        padding-left:10px;
        padding-right:10px;
    }
     .auto-style3 {
         color:Gray;
     }
 </style>
    <link href="Styles/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/tinybox2/tinybox.js"></script>
    <link href="Scripts/tinybox2/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery-ui.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $("#accordion").accordion({
                collapsible: true,
                heightStyle: "content"
            });
        });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h3> <span class="auto-style3">Welcome</span>&nbsp;
    <asp:Label ID="lastNameHolder" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="auto-style3"></asp:Label>,
    &nbsp; 
    <asp:Label ID="firstNameHolder" runat="server" Text="Label" CssClass="auto-style3"></asp:Label>
    </h3>
    <div id="accordion">
        <h3>Step 1: Complete Optional Information</h3>
    <div>Displ some box <br /></div>
    <h3>Step 2: Take Assessment</h3>
    <div id="divStep2" runat="server"><div class="btnHolder"><asp:Button ID="btnAssessStart" runat="server" Text="Start Your Assessment" /></div></div>
    <h3>Step 3: Review Responses</h3>
    <div>
           <asp:LinqDataSource ID="linqDSUserResponse" runat="server" 
            ContextTypeName="BCEE_KAIV2.kaiDataContext" EntityTypeName="" 
            TableName="tblAssessmentQuestions">
        </asp:LinqDataSource>

        <asp:GridView ID="gvDisplayUserResponse" runat="server" 
            AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="questionPK" 
            DataSourceID="linqDSUserResponse">
            <Columns>
                <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="True" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblItemNum" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="questionPK" SortExpression="questionPK" 
                    Visible="False">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("questionPK") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("questionPK") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="questionPresentationOrder" HeaderText="questionPresentationOrder" 
                    SortExpression="questionPresentationOrder" Visible="False" 
                    InsertVisible="False" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="questionChoice1Text" 
                    HeaderText="questionChoice1Text" 
                    SortExpression="questionChoice1Text" />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <div id="slider"> </div>
                </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="questionChoice2Text" 
                    HeaderText="questionChoice2Text" SortExpression="questionChoice2Text" />
                <asp:CheckBoxField DataField="questionStatus" HeaderText="questionStatus" 
                    SortExpression="questionStatus" Visible="False" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    <h3>Step 4: Evaluate Assessment</h3>
        <div><div class="btnHolder"><asp:Button  ID="evaluateAssessment" runat="server" Text="Evaluate Your Assessment"/></div></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
         function open_win() {
             window.open("AssessmentLoggedIn.aspx", "_self");
         }
</script>

    </asp:Content>
```

and my code behind

```
Protected Sub gvDisplayUserResponse_RowCreated(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles gvDisplayUserResponse.RowCreated

    If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

        Dim myUserID As String = "13-zTest1RaffertyRichard0000"
        Dim myRowNumLabel As Label = CType(e.Row.Cells(1).Controls(1), Label)
        Dim myQuestionID As Guid = New Guid(gvDisplayUserResponse.DataKeys(e.Row.RowIndex).Value.ToString)

        myRowNumLabel.Text = e.Row.RowIndex.ToString() + 1

        Dim cxt As kaiDataContext = New kaiDataContext

        Dim myUserInput = From ui In cxt.tblAssesseeResults
                        Where ui.assesseeUniqueID = myUserID And
                              ui.assesseeQuestionID = myQuestionID
                        Select ui.assesseeResponseScore

        Dim mySliderValue As Integer = 0

        For Each mui In myUserInput
            mySliderValue = CType(mui, Integer)
        Next

        Dim csname As String = "userResponseSlider"
        Dim cstype As Type = Me.GetType()
        Dim cs As ClientScriptManager = Page.ClientScript

        If (Not cs.IsClientScriptBlockRegistered(cstype, csname)) Then
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder()

            sb.Append("(function () {")
            sb.Append("$('#slider').slider({")
            sb.Append("value: ")
            sb.AppendFormat("{0}", mySliderValue)
            sb.Append(", min: 10, max: 90, step: 1")
            sb.Append(" }); }); ")
            cs.RegisterStartupScript(cstype, csname, sb.ToString(), True)
        End If
    End If


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, the `key` parameter in `RegisterStartupScript` is unique, so if this code is being called for multiple rows, only the first script block will actually be rendered to the page.

I don't think that's your main issue though. Open your javascript console and look for errors, and view the source of the page and make sure you actually have 1) divs with an id of "slider" and 2) the client script to render the sliders rendered on the page.